# Square focus color

Tags: square-connect

Using the Square payment form (`sqPaymentForm`) in context with the API how do I set the `color` property for text for the focus state? I have been vaguely able to emulate a `background-color` property in a hackish fashion though would appreciate being able to apply the `background-color` property for the iframe/form field focus state in a more proper approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form#adjustingexteriorstyles), that page describes all styling options that are available.